# Writing and reading data simultaneously in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android app and I am writing some data in firebase.

```
{
  "movies" : {
        "movie2" : {
              "movieId" : "movie2",
              "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
              "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/kabali.jpg",
              "movieTitle" : "Kabali (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
              "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
        },
        "movie3" : {
              "movieId" : "movie3",
              "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
              "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/pic09.jpg",
              "movieTitle" : "Movie Demo (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
              "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
        }
  }
}
```

I am adding a child `movieLotteryTicket` under `movie2` node after this  (in a same click)  adding the updated `movie2` node under a different section named `userFavourites`
But I am not getting the updated `movie2` node in `userFavourites`

```
{
  "movies" : {
        "movie2" : {
              "movieId" : "movie2",
              "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
              "movieLotteryTicket" : {
                  "aaaa@gmail.com" : "12300"
              },
              "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/kabali.jpg",
              "movieTitle" : "Kabali (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
              "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
        },
        "movie3" : {
              "movieId" : "movie3",
              "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
              "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/pic09.jpg",
              "movieTitle" : "Movie Demo (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
              "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
        }
  },
  "userFavourites" : {
        "bbbb@gmail,com" : {
              "movie2" : {
                "movieId" : "movie2",
                "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
                "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/kabali.jpg",
                "movieTitle" : "Kabali (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
                "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
              }
        }
  }
}
```

When I delete the `movie2` node in `userFavourites` and add again with same button click now I am getting correct updated `movie2` node

```
{
  "movies" : {
        "movie2" : {
              "movieId" : "movie2",
              "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
              "movieLotteryTicket" : {
                  "aaaa@gmail.com" : "12300"
              },
              "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/kabali.jpg",
              "movieTitle" : "Kabali (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
              "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
        },
        "movie3" : {
              "movieId" : "movie3",
              "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
              "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/pic09.jpg",
              "movieTitle" : "Movie Demo (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
              "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
        }
  },
  "userFavourites" : {
        "bbbb@gmail,com" : {
              "movie2" : {
                "movieId" : "movie2",
                "movieReleaseDate" : "7/10/2018",
                "movieLotteryTicket" : {
                    "aaaa@gmail.com" : "12300"
                },
                "movieThumbnail" : "http://flp.businessofboxoffice.com/images/kabali.jpg",
                "movieTitle" : "Kabali (2018 Film) - Official Trailer",
                "movieYoutubeLink" : "https://youtu.be/9wY_vb4pkLs"
              }
        }
  }
}
```

Here is my code when I click button

```
    public void OnMovieClicked(final Movie movie, View view) {

                  // geting movieLotteryTicket

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = ((RelativeLayout) view);
        StringBuilder lottery = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < relativeLayout.getChildCount();i++){
            View v = relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if(v.getId()==R.id.checkBoxLottery1){
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    lottery.append("1");
                }
                else {
                    lottery.append("0");

                }
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.checkBoxLottery2){
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    lottery.append("2");
                }
                else {
                    lottery.append("0");
                }
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.checkBoxLottery3){
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    lottery.append("3");
                }
                else {
                    lottery.append("0");
                }
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.checkBoxLottery4){
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    lottery.append("4");
                }
                else {
                    lottery.append("0");
                }
            }
            if(v.getId()==R.id.checkBoxLottery5){
                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    lottery.append("5");
                }
                else {
                    lottery.append("0");
                }
            }
        }
        final String finalLottery = lottery.toString();
        final DatabaseReference lotteryDatabaseReference;
        lotteryDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("movies").child(movie.getmovieId()).child("movieLotteryTicket");

        lotteryDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(Constants.encodeEmail(mUserEmailString)).getValue()!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Already bought Lottery for this movie ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child(Constants.encodeEmail(mUserEmailString)).setValue(finalLottery);
                    Toasa t.makeText(getActivity(),"Thanks for buying lottery tickets....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

            // adding movie to user Favourites

        if (Constants.isIncludedInMap(mFavouriteMoviesMarkedMap,movie)){
            mGetAllFavouriteMoviesMarkedReference.child(movie.getmovieId())
                    .removeValue();

            mCompositeSubscription.add(mLiveMoviesService.addOrRemoveFavourite(mSocket,mUserEmailString,
                    movie.getmovieId(),"1"));
        } else{
            mGetAllFavouriteMoviesMarkedReference.child(movie.getmovieId())
                    .setValue(movie);

            mCompositeSubscription.add(mLiveMoviesService.addOrRemoveFavourite(mSocket,mUserEmailString,
                    movie.getmovieId(),"0"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankvanPuffelen for the suggestion, updated the question